# Problem astro blog to get linked page to display page content instead of source code

Tags: html, debugging, routes, astrojs

## Description

Inside my 'index.astro' I am trying to set up links to another page inside a 'Card.astro', when I try to navigate to a different page the page will only show the source code.

```
<Card
        href="src/pages/getting-in-shape.astro"
        title="Documentation"
        body="Learn how Astro works and explore the official API docs."
      />
```

### Steps to Reproduce

Get the development environment from my  [github repo](https://github.com/chr1swill/astro-blog-website/tree/main). Open up the project, in the terminal run "npm run dev" open the local host link, then click on the first card with the title "Documentation". For me, this only leads to the source code of the page.

### Expected Behaviour

I expected that this would open the page, compile the content, and allow the user to navigate to a different page.

### Actual Behaviour

What is actually happening is that the page is routing as expected, but the page is only showing the source code. If you inspect the code (Ctrl + Shift + I) you can see  all this same code that is on screen, but none of it is formatted as you would expect it to. It also is not detected the style sheet.  It is almost as if I have formatted everything for astro to be used but did not use it.

### Error Messages

There are no errors showing, not any problem detected in my VsCode either. It is almost as if I have done someone that make a disconnect between my code and what is happening in the web browser.

### Environment

- **Operating System:** Windows 10 Version 22H2 (OS Build 19045.3208)
- **Programming Language and Tools:** I am working with JavaScript, Node.js(v19.9.0), HTML, CSS, Markdown
- **Framework, Libraries, Preprocessors:** Astro and  SCSS
- **Dependency Manager:** Node Package Manager

**Hardware Information:**

- Processor        AMD Ryzen 5 3500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx     2.10 * * GHz
- Installed RAM        8.00 GB (5.94 GB usable)
- System type          64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

Answer (score 0):

**The issue you are facing with seeing the source code of the page instead of the expected content could be due to various reasons.**

**Astro Configuration:**
If you are using Astro (a static site builder) for your project, check the Astro configuration to make sure that the file extensions and routing settings are correctly configured. Astro uses a specialized file format, so it's essential to ensure that your pages are properly set up within the Astro framework.

or

**Check Browser Console:**
Open the browser developer tools and check the console for any error messages. There might be errors related to file loading, server issues, or incorrect file paths.

If you've gone through these steps and the issue persists, please provide more specific details about your project's setup, file structure, and any error messages you see in the browser console. This additional information will help in identifying the root cause of the problem and providing a more targeted solution

Comment: I tested out you suggested fixes and turns to was a configuration problem. A silly mistake on my part i didn't realize that setting up the routes in the "astro.config.mjs" is **vital** for getting you pages to compile and not just show the source code. Thanks you for your wisdom my friend.